# Apple Fitness - Change what value gets shown in the Workouts List

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, watchos, hkhealthstore

Me and my team are currently working on a standalone watchOS App, where we are tracking workouts with `HKLiveWorkoutBuilder`. Just before calling the `finishWorkout(completion:)` method that saves the workout into the `HKHealthStore` we are saving some metadata when necessary to the workout.

However, we would also like to change the *green value* in the Fitness App that defaults to the workout duration to active/total KCAL just as it is visible on the entry saved from the Health App. The *green value* is displayed in the iOS' Fitness App list of the workouts just under the workout name as seen on the screenshot below. We have also done some research on the AppStore and there are 3rd party apps which saved workouts actually show the KCAL in the Fitness App, therefore it seems like there is some way around it.

Unfortunately we were unable to find matching `HKMetadataKey` in the docs, nor could we find any other possible solution.

We will be very grateful for any tips!
Stay safe :)

[image: iOS Fitness App]

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong. you are trying to save data in health app using your app.

Comment: Saving workouts directly from the Apple Watch (`HKLiveWorkoutBuilder` + `HKWorkoutSession`) by calling `finishWorkout(completion:)` on the `HKLiveWorkoutBuilder` instance. Calling the `finishWorkout(completion:)` saves the workout into the `HKHealthStore` from which the health data + workouts are shown in the Health/Fitness App on the paired iPhone. So to answer your question, yes, saving data (the live workout) in Health App (by saving to `HKHealthStore`) using our app.

Comment: see here : https://www.raywenderlich.com/6992-healthkit-tutorial-with-swift-workouts

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that unfortunately doesn't help us with our goal of changing the *green value* in the Fitness App.

Comment: if you refer that tutorial it will saved workout data into `Healthkit` that's why i refer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our team managed to get a response from Apple Engineers in this matter and they have said that there is no API to achieve that for 3rd party developers.